# OneToMany Composite Primary key scenario

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I have the following scenario, avoiding obvious code:

An object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "poliza")
public class Polizas implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "numero_poliza")
    private BigDecimal numero;
}
```

one or more child objects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Autos")
@IdClass(AutosPk.class)
public class Autos {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "auto_id")
    private BigDecimal autoId;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "numero_poliza")
    private Polizas poliza;
}
```

The Primary key class:

```
public class AutosPk {
    private BigDecimal autoId;
    private BigDecimal poliza;
}
```

Up to this point everything works fine.
But if I need to modify Autos to this (Adding a list of other objects):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Autos")
@IdClass(AutosPk.class)
public class Autos {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "auto_id")
    private BigDecimal autoId;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "numero_poliza")
    private Polizas poliza;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "auto_id", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<AccesoriosAutos> accesorios;
}
```

And the child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "acce_auto")
@IdClass(AccesoriosAutosPk.class)
public class AccesoriosAutos {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "cod_acces")
    private BigDecimal codAcces;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "numero_poliza", referencedColumnName = "numero_poliza"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "cod_auto", referencedColumnName = "cod_auto")})
    private Autos auto;
}
```

and in the primary key class:

```
public class AccesoriosAutosPk {
    private BigDecimal codAcces;
    private AutosPk auto;
}
```

The mapping described is wrong, but I posted this way because I think it explains my need. I've search through several pages, but i just can´t find the way to do this mapping.

Thanks in advance for reading,

Juan Romero

Answer (score 0):

I have a few things to mention from my point of view:

1. It is strange you are using @IdClass with @Id.
2. Autos class should annotate accesorios as @OneToMany(mappedBy = "auto", ....)
3. AccesoriosAuto auto column just annotate with @JoinColumn(name="cod_auto")

Hope this helps.

Comment: I follow 2 and 3 and I get 
The JoinColumns on the annotated element [field auto] from the entity class [class AccesoriosAutos] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such JoinColumn.

Comment: For 1, If I drop the Id annotation I get:
Exception Description: Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class [class AccesoriosAutosPk] and those of the entity bean class [class AccesoriosAutos] must correspond and their types must be the same. Also, ensure that you have specified ID elements for the corresponding attributes in XML and/or an @Id on the corresponding fields or properties of the entity class.
So, I understand I need to have both. Am I wrong?